# C# Winform How to change form nonclient area size？

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, winapi

I've already implemented a change to the size of the nonclient area but encountered a problem.

[image: Click here see demo.jpg]

> Bug : Whenever I maximize the window and restore it again, its width
>   and height will increase.

This is my code:

```
private void WmNcCalcSize(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.WParam != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        Win32.NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS rcsize = (Win32.NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS)Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(Win32.NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS));
        AdjustClientRect(ref rcsize.rcNewWindow);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(rcsize, m.LParam, false);
    }
    else
    {
        Win32.RECT rcsize = (Win32.RECT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(Win32.RECT));
        AdjustClientRect(ref rcsize);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(rcsize, m.LParam, false);
    }

    m.Result = (IntPtr)1;
}

private void AdjustClientRect(ref Win32.RECT rcClient)
{
    if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
    {
        rcClient.top += this.CaptionHeight + Math.Abs(this.Top) - 1;
        rcClient.left = 0;

        rcClient.right = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Right;
        rcClient.bottom -= 1;
    }
    else
    {
        rcClient.top += this.CaptionHeight;
        rcClient.left += 1;
        rcClient.right -= 1;
        rcClient.bottom -= 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I noticed this problem as well when tinkering with WM_NCCALCSIZE a while ago.  Ultimately gave up on because of too many gritty issues, this was one of them.  Winforms cares a lot more about ClientSize than Size and the underlying code is very messy.  I *think* you need to override SizeFromCientSize(), but that's a guess that I didn't try at the time.  Look at the private RestoreWindowBoundsIfNecessary() in Form.cs if that doesn't get you anywhere.

Comment: @HansPassant :Thanks, I'll try it, if can't, I guess I can only start with Form.RestroeBoudns.

Comment: You could always do it the easy way; manually store the non-maximized size, and use those values to reset the size when the window is restored.

Comment: You'd better just drop a panel for your container.  Position, size and anchor it accordingly and use it as a container for all other controls.  This is much more reliable than any arcane tricks you can do with the client size.

Comment: @Nyerguds: Indeed, that would be an option. If the system didn't blatantly lie to you about the true window dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually tried to intercept the WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED message to control it:

```
    private void WmWindowPosChanged(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);

        curWindowState = this.WindowState;

        if (curWindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized || curWindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized
            && preWindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
        {
            restoreRectangle = this.RestoreBounds;
        }

        if (curWindowState == FormWindowState.Normal
            && preWindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized || curWindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            if (restoreRectangle != Rectangle.Empty)
                this.Size = restoreRectangle.Size;

            restoreRectangle = Rectangle.Empty;
        }

        preWindowState = curWindowState;
    }
```